# Redirecting a drupal user based on their role

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have a page on my website that I want to redirect users to different pages based on their role.

I tried to make a module to put `mymodule_init()` to redirect users.

I check with `arg(0)` my page but cannot figure out how to redirect user based on role.

How do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `$user` variable since its a global variable by putting

```
global $user;
```

At the beginning of your logic. Then you can check the user role with something like:

```
if (in_array('myrole', $user->roles)) {
  drupal_goto('page');
}
```